# Semi-supervised learning for regression

Tags: regression, semi-supervised-learning

It is mentioned on [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html) that `Label Propagation` of `scikit-learn` can be used for regression also. However, nothing is mentioned on [its API page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelPropagation.html#sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelPropagation).

How can I do semi-supervised learning for regression with `Label Propagation` or any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an error in the documentation as the target is validated to be a classification target.

```
 check_classification_targets(y)
```

The default label propagation would however just propagate the existing 'labels' i.e. regression values, so not much would be gained in this case.